# Why std::array does not contain an initializer-list constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

In order to initialize a `std::array` with some values, you need to use this approach:

```
std::array<int,3> an_array{{3,4,5}};
```

I am aware of the reason that we need two curly braces (one for `std::array` and the the other for the inner `c-style array`).

**My question:** Why, by standard, `std::array` does not contain an initializer-list constructor that directly initialize the inner `c-style array`? Is not more eyes-friendly to be initialized as:

```
std::array<int,3> an_array{3,4,5};
```

**Edit:**

This information is from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array. I thought my compiler is allowing the second version directly as non-standard extension. Now, I am not even sure what is the standard exactly about this case.

> // construction uses aggregate initialization
>
> `std::array<int, 3> a1{ {1, 2, 3} };` // double-braces required in C++11 (not in C++14)

Comment: what compiler are you using? works here: https://godbolt.org/g/ogju8j

Comment: ah I see: that got fixed with c++14. See here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array so this was likely unintended.

Comment: @Hayt it's called *brace elision*

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki thanks. I am always bad with remembering the correct terms of things :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard defines `std::array` as follows (N3337 for C++11, but the quoted parts are identical in N4140):

> §23.3.2.1 [array.overview]/2
>
> An array is an aggregate that can be initialized with the syntax
>
> ```
> array<T, N> a = { initializer-list };
> ```

and an aggregate is defined as:

> §8.5.1 [dcl.init.aggr]/1
>
> An aggregate is an array or a class with no user-provided
>   constructors, no private or protected non-static data members, no base
>   classes, and no virtual functions.

So it cannot have a user-defined constructor, which an `initializer_list` one would be.

---

Additionally, C++11 defines brace elision only for the `T x = { a }` syntax:

> §8.5.1 [dcl.init.aggr]/11
>
> In a declaration of the form
>
> ```
> T x = { a };
> ```
>
> braces can be elided in an *initializer-list* as follows. [...]

whereas C++14 (N4140) lifts this requirement:

> §8.5.1 [dcl.init.aggr]/11
>
> Braces can be elided in an *initializer-list* as follows. [...]

So the following is perfectly valid C++14 and above:

```
std::array<int,3> an_array{3,4,5}
```

Comment: Thanks... in other words, it can not contain user-defined constructor so they solve the problem in C++ 14 by brace illusion.. right?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi yes, they changed the rules for all aggregates: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1270

Comment: The answer could be completed by §8.5.1 [dcl.init.agr] item 12 (in specification draft N4296 and probably the same item in earlier versions): "Braces can be elided in an initializer-list as follows..." this specification item explains why one can removes the inner brace when initializing an aggregate.

Comment: @Oliv edited, thanks.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you don't even see the sleight of hand, and your braces are gone!

Comment: It's amazing! The Fantastic Illusory Braces! Roll up, roll up...